# Retrieve DE fields in order via SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I am trying to retrieve DE fields via SOAP API but the response containing the fields is out of order not even in alphabetical. I need them to be in the exact order as what is in the UI. I need this to create the same exact DE in another instance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you retrieve the 'ordinal' property of the fields, this will tell you the order they are stored/were created, and appear in the UI.  You can sort on that via code before creating the new DE/fields.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Data Extension rows returned via SOAP call are always returned in the order in which they were added.  You cannot apply any other sort(s), such as alphabetical, to your SOAP requests to retrieve them in any other order.